# Append a popup to body on click with Angular (and then remove)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around the directive concept in Angular.

I want to show a modal box when clicking on a link. The contents of the modal box is dynamic. In jQuery it would be an easy `$("body").append(myModal)` and then simply `remove()` it from the DOM when closed.

Now I'd like to do the same in pure Angular. This is what I have so far:

A controller function:

```
$scope.userLogout = function() {
    notification.show();
};
```

A service:

```
.service('notification', ['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
        var notification = {
            open: false,
            show : function() {
                this.open = true;
            },
            hide: function() {
                this.open = false;
            }
        };
        return notification;
    }
])
```

A directive:

```
.directive('notification', ['notification',
    function(notification){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: (notification.open) ? '<div class="myModal"></div>' : ''
        }
}])
```

How do I update the directive when the value in my service changes? Or is this the right approach at all?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, with something like Angular, it's possible to simply use `data-ng-show` and `data-ng-hide` on an element styled like a modal. Depending on your use case, you may not need to create a directive to achieve what you want. Consider the following:

HTML:

```
...
<div data-ng-show="notification.open" class="modalPopup">
    ...
    {{notification.my_modal_message}}
    ...
    <button data-ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
</div>
```

JS (simplified):

```
function myCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.notification = {
        my_modal_message: "Bender's back, baby!",
        open: false
    }

    $scope.logout = function () {
        // logout stuff
        logout().success(function () {
            // open the modal
            $scope.notification.open = true;
        }
    }

    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.notification.open = false;
    }
}
```

At times, it's much better to make a full directive to do something like this for you. However, again - depending on your use case - this may be all you need. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about doing it this way, but from one side it's more than just a message that needs to be inserted between those tags, and on the other side I'd like to really understand the possibilities of using directives in general, and linking them with services like in this particular case. I give you +1 though for providing a valid and simple workaround for the problem :)